# Finding first alphabetical letter in a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I've done some research and can't seem to find a way to do this. I even tried using a for loop to loop through the string and tried using the functions `isLetter()` and `charAt(`).
I have a string which is a street address for example:

```
var streetAddr = "45 Church St";
```

I need a way to loop through the string and find the first alphabetical letter in that string. I need to use that character somewhere else after this. For the above example I would need the function to return a value of **C**. What would be a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe one of the shortest solutions:

```
'45 Church St'.match(/[a-zA-Z]/).pop();
```

Since `match` will return `null` if there are no alphanumerical characters in a string, you may transform it to the following fool proof solution:

```
('45 Church St'.match(/[a-zA-Z]/) || []).pop();
```

Comment: I must admit after trying this solution, it is the best out of all of them.

Comment: Or `'45 Church St'.replace(/^[^a-z]+/ig,'').substr(0,1)` avoids the issues with *match*. Also `('45 Church St'.match(/[a-z]/i) || []).pop()` saves 2 characters. :-)

Comment: Oh, there's also `'45 Church St'.replace(/^[^a-z]+/ig,'')[0]` but IE doesn't like that. :-(

Answer (score 7):

Just check if the character is in the range A-Z or a-z

```
function firstChar(inputString) {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i += 1) {
        if ((inputString.charAt(i) >= 'A' && inputString.charAt(i) <= 'Z') || 
            (inputString.charAt(i) >= 'a' && inputString.charAt(i) <= 'z')) {
            return inputString.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

console.assert(firstChar("45 Church St") === "C");
console.assert(firstChar("12345") === "");
```

Comment: +1 Because OP says `I need a way to loop through the string and ...`

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code, and the OP asked for a loop, but it's a great example of why regexes are worth the initial pain of learning.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with `match`

```
"45 Church St".match(/[a-z]/i)[0]; // "C"
```

Comment: I've never used match before, where does the "C" value go to?

Comment: Currently it's not "going" anywhere, the line evaluates to it. You can use an `=` or a `return` or whatever you want to access it elsewhere

Comment: Though there *will* be another problem if the source string doesn't have any alphanumerical characters.

Answer (score 0):

This code example should get the job done.

```
function numsNletters(alphanum) {
    firstChar=alphanum.match(/[a-zA-Z]/).pop();
    numsLetters=alphanum.split(firstChar);
    numbers=numsLetters[0];
    // prepending the letter we split on (found with regex at top)
    letters=firstChar+numsLetters[1];
    return numbers+'|'+letters;
}
```

numsNletters("123abc"); // returns "123|abc";